# Do I use Light, Dark, Default, or HighContrast when writing ThemeDictionaries?

Tags: xaml, uwp, themes, winui

I've seen lots of different keys used in ThemeDictionaries in UWP/WinUI XAML: `Light`, `Dark`, `Default`, & `HighContrast`. However, these seem partially redundant.

**Which ones should I use?**

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources) recommend `Light`, `Dark`, and `HighContrast`:

> Specify theme dictionaries for both "Light" and "Dark" in addition to your "HighContrast" dictionary. Although you can create a ResourceDictionary with "Default" as the key, it's preferred to be explicit and instead use "Light", "Dark", and "HighContrast".

But official WinUI controls like [`DropDownButton`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/winui2/main/dev/DropDownButton/DropDownButton_themeresources.xaml) use `Default`, `Light`, and `HighContrast`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondary" ResourceKey="TextFillColorSecondaryBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondaryPointerOver" ResourceKey="TextFillColorTertiaryBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondaryPressed" ResourceKey="TextFillColorTertiaryBrush"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondary" ResourceKey="TextFillColorSecondaryBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondaryPointerOver" ResourceKey="TextFillColorTertiaryBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondaryPressed" ResourceKey="TextFillColorTertiaryBrush"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondary" ResourceKey="SystemColorButtonTextColorBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondaryPointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemColorHighlightColorBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DropDownButtonForegroundSecondaryPressed" ResourceKey="SystemColorHighlightColorBrush"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

How do I choose which keys to use?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the official `Default`, `Light` and `HighContrast` implementing `Default` as `Dark`, which will be applied when the requested theme is not found.